# Where to find databases from physics experiments?

Tags: experimental-physics, resource-recommendations, data-analysis, data

In some lecture I want to write about data analysis in physics I want to show some real uses of data analysis tools in the analysis of data from real experiments. I tried to search but I couldn't find some site that has a variety of databases from different experiments that I can use. Do someone know where could I find such a thing?

Comment: CERN Open Data (http://opendata.cern.ch/) might be a good place to start.

Comment: The second easiest source I know (and the best one) would be going down to a local institution of higher learning and chatting up some physicists until you feel comfortable *asking* them what they might be will to give you. Of course, you *can* get some of the data coming out of the big LHC experiments (along with the tools to work on it), but ... it's a month-plus project for a particle physics post-doc to get up to speed on a new analysis from a standing start. Similar comments apply to SDDS data and the other really big "we open the data after a year" astronomy arrangements.

Comment: What level is this at? If this is freshman mechanics, then you don't want to analyze LHC data.